# Is there a way to make customer modify their information via website?

Tags: webservices, web

i want to create a profile page on our portal that displays user information, So far I came up with "Email us if you want to change your information." solution, But I don't want to do it manually I want them to be able to do it themselves without our team having to do it. Is it possible on salesforce ? We're using the enterprise edition. I know salesforce allows you to do a web to lead form that will put their information onto a lead. So i thought it would be possible to do for a User as well.

```
<apex:outputText style="font-size:50px" rendered="{!NOT(ISPICKVAL($User.UserType,'Guest'))}"> {!$User.FirstName} </apex:outputText>
<apex:outputText style="font-size:50px" rendered="{!NOT(ISPICKVAL($User.UserType,'Guest'))}"> {!$User.LastName} </apex:outputText>
<apex:outputText style="font-size:50px" rendered="{!NOT(ISPICKVAL($User.UserType,'Guest'))}"> {!$User.Alias} </apex:outputText>
<apex:outputText style="font-size:50px" rendered="{!NOT(ISPICKVAL($User.UserType,'Guest'))}"> {!$User.Email} </apex:outputText>
<apex:outputText style="font-size:50px" rendered="{!NOT(ISPICKVAL($User.UserType,'Guest'))}"> {!$User.Title} </apex:outputText>
<apex:outputText style="font-size:50px" rendered="{!NOT(ISPICKVAL($User.UserType,'Guest'))}"> {!$User.Department} </apex:outputText>
<apex:outputText style="font-size:50px" rendered="{!NOT(ISPICKVAL($User.UserType,'Guest'))}"> {!$User.Division} </apex:outputText>
<apex:outputText style="font-size:50px" rendered="{!NOT(ISPICKVAL($User.UserType,'Guest'))}"> {!$User.Address} </apex:outputText>
<apex:outputText style="font-size:50px" rendered="{!NOT(ISPICKVAL($User.UserType,'Guest'))}"> {!$User.MobilePhone} </apex:outputText>
<apex:outputText style="font-size:50px" rendered="{!NOT(ISPICKVAL($User.UserType,'Guest'))}"> {!$User.Fax} </apex:outputText>
<apex:outputText style="font-size:50px" rendered="{!NOT(ISPICKVAL($User.UserType,'Guest'))}"> {!$User.Phone} </apex:outputText>
```

So far I was checking if the information gets displayed. I know it's simple but it will get changed after I find a way to modify it

Comment: This is a SalesForce Site, right?  (publicly available, possibly secured w/ a sign-in)

Comment: Yes its a visualforce page with a sign in function.

Comment: As long as the user has rights to modify the User record you can do this.

I'm assuming the fields above are what you want them to be able to update. I would just put an 'edit' button on the form and when it is selected hide your outputText fields and instead display inputText fields with the same info. Then a simple 'save' button.

Comment: I don't think the user has access to the actual salesforce server it's just a portal for ordering purposes. If they want to make an account they have to email us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this a VF page you just need to follow some simple steps.

1. In your portal display these value in editable format(use `apex:inputfield or apex:inputtext`).
2. Now when your user click on save , update these values. You can do this using apex code.

Try these steps and share if you get success or if you stuck anywhere community is always ready to help you.

Comment: hey, thanks a lot I will try it and let you know if it works.